# Query Mongo date field(set by js date) using ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

Essentially i have a form which takes mm-dd-yy, this value is saved in a database (Value A).

I am using ruby on rails. I am trying to query the database for expired users.

```
query.push(:expire_date => {:$lt => Time.parse(good_till).utc} )
```

Problem I am encountering is that the date I pass in the good_till I can convert to UTC using this ruby command, however now i am checking a UTC value to a string.

How do I change my js code in order to save Value A into UTC string to make the two comparable?

Comment: Changed it. Didn't release that functionality. Can you help out? :)

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer but you must make sure the type in your document is the same as the one in your query. So either use ISODate for both or use a string for both. The former is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

I think your :expire_field declaration is incorrect.
Well, it depends on which mongo framework you're using on ruby's app.
Assuming you're using MongoID, you just have to declare your model like this:

```
class Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :expire_date, type: DateTime   
end
```